# PHP echo problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have one function and my echo is:

```
echo '<tr>
<td align="center" style="padding:5px;"><img src="/chat/emotes/smile.png" onclick="insertSmiley("hallo")"> <br>:illuminati:</td>
               </tr>'
```

The problem is that `onclick="insertSmiley("hallo")"` must be with `'` and not with `"`. If I put this in html everything works, but in nothing happens in php echo when I click.

My index.php have this script in body:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function insertSmiley(smiley) 
    { 

        var currentText = document.getElementById("send"); 

        var smileyWithPadding = " " + smiley + " "; 
        currentText.value += smileyWithPadding; 
    currentText.focus(); 

    } 
</script>
```

and the other code is in my chat.php:

```
    echo '<textarea id="send" maxlength="125" rows="2" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="padding:5px;"><img src="/chat/emotes/smile.png" onclick="insertSmiley("hallo")"> <br>:illuminati:</td>
                   </tr>
```

I really think that the problem is because I cant use `''` in echo and I need it for `onClick...('hallo')`.

Comment: You're missing `;` at the end of your first `echo` statement and the second `echo` statement is missing `';` at the end, also!

Comment: You have error in javascript double quote inside double quote use `onclick="insertSmiley(\'hallo\')"`

Comment: You're generating bad html: `onclick="insertSmiley("hallo")">`. The first `"` quote for `hallo` is terminating your onclick attribute, meaning the JS code inside the onclick is a syntax error.

Comment: Yes i see that it's because i didn't put all the code here but thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `\'` to just print `'`

Backslashes are used in PHP to escape special characters within quotes. As PHP does not distinguish between strings and characters

If your write like this

```
echo 'check it \' out';
```

it will give output like this

```
check it ' out
```

So use like this

```
echo '<tr>
<td align="center" style="padding:5px;"><img src="/chat/emotes/smile.png" onclick="insertSmiley(\'hallo\')"> <br>:illuminati:</td>
               </tr>'
```

Comment: Need to wait 8 min to accept the answer i will wait and accept it Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are not echoing any variable within the `echo` statement, simply add the PHP tags outside of your code:

```
//Your PHP code here
?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding:5px;">
                <img src="/chat/emotes/smile.png" onclick='insertSmiley(" hallo")'>
                <br>:illuminati:
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php

// Continue your php code
```

In case you have to echo a variable in your HTML, do it this way:

```
$greetings = "Hallo";

    //Your PHP code here
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="padding:5px;">
                    <img src="/chat/emotes/smile.png" onclick="insertSmiley('<?php echo $greetings; ?>')">
                    <br>:illuminati:
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php

   echo "<textarea id="send" maxlength="125" rows="2" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td align="center" style="padding:5px;"><img src="/chat/emotes/smile.png" onclick="insertSmiley("hallo")"> <br>:illuminati:</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
onclick="insertSmiley(\'hallo\')"
```